# SQl Server split delimited string into rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table in SQL Server 2008 database, the table has two columns,as follow:

[image]

I want to select the data as following:

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647/how-do-i-split-a-string-so-i-can-access-item-x

Comment: Best thing you could do is fix this so the table is properly normalized in the first place. Storing delimited data is columns is really bad. But I know that's not always possible.

Comment: Side note: SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 are **out of extended support** by now - https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/ - time to upgrade!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This type of operation is rather painful in SQL Server, because the built-in string functions are pretty bad.  The referenced question uses a `while` loop -- which is unnecessary.  You can construct this all in one query using a recursive CTE:

```
with t as (
      select 'ali' as col1, 'A;B;C' as col2
     ),
     cte as (
      select col1,
             convert(varchar(max), left(col2, charindex(';', col2) - 1)) as val,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(col2, 1, charindex(';', col2), '') + ';') as rest
      from t
      union all
      select col1,
             convert(varchar(max), left(rest, charindex(';', rest) - 1)) as val,
             convert(varchar(max), stuff(rest, 1, charindex(';', rest), '')) as rest
      from cte
      where rest <> ''
     )
select cte.*
from cte;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar situation and I solved it using XML querying with this as my [guide](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1771/splitting-delimited-strings-using-xml-in-sql-server/). I am not super proficient with XML queries, so I am hesitant to share my answer because I cannot fully explain it line by line even though it does work. What I do understand is that you replace your separator character (or string) with closing and opening XML tags with a open tag at the very beginning and a close tag at the very end which transforms this...

```
A;B;C
```

into this...

```
<X>A</X>
<X>B</X>
<X>C</X>
```

You can use XML query syntax to retrieve each of those nodes. There is nothing magical about "X" other than you have to use the same tag in the nodes() method in CROSS APPLY section.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
    Column1 VARCHAR(20)
  , Column2 VARCHAR(50)
);

INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2) VALUES ('Ali', 'A;B;C');
INSERT INTO Table1 (Column1, Column2) VALUES ('Ahmed', 'D;E');

DECLARE @Separator VARCHAR(10);
SET @Separator = ';';


SELECT      a.Column1
          , b.SplitData
FROM        (
                SELECT Column1
                     , CAST('<X>' + REPLACE((
                                                SELECT Column2 AS [*] FOR XML PATH('')
                                            )
                                          , @Separator
                                          , '</X><X>'
                                           ) + '</X>' AS XML) xmlfilter
                FROM   Table1
            ) AS a
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT LetterIDs.Column2.value('.', 'varchar(50)') AS SplitData
                FROM   a.xmlfilter.nodes('X') AS LetterIDs(Column2)
            ) AS b;
```

Here is the [db fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0b408f9dece7374f5c843acc107e62d5). I hope this helps.