# Extracting somewhat reliably placed substrings from a longer string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I have a dataset that looks roughly like this:

```
01/02/2022, "bananas, apples and oranges", "accepted", "John"   
01/05/2022, "bananas and grapes", "accepted", "Mary"  
01/08/2022, "kale and bananas", "rejected", "John"
```

I need to transform it into:

```
01/02/2022, "bananas", "accepted", "John"
01/02/2022, "apples", "accepted", "John"
01/02/2022, "oranges", "accepted", "John"
01/05/2022, "bananas, "accepted", "Mary"
```

etc.

My problem is extracting the substrings for the types of fruit. The pattern is reliable in that the last delimiter is always " and ", and if there is another one before it, it's always ", ". So I can use CHARINDEX to find the position of the start of each word. But I struggle with finding the position of the end of the word. I could probably do it with a ton of CASE WHENs but is there an easier way?

(I asked this question earlier but I did a bad job of describing the problem then.)

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Comment: Are we looking at 2 columns here or 4? Include the actual table schema / columns to make it clear. Are double quotes part of the data??

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to split a delimited string into multiple rows. There are many questions in SO related to this, such as this [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57245618/sql-server-split-delimited-string-into-rows).

Comment: I'd suggest you use a proper format such as JSON or XML, it would be far easier to parse in SQL. But if that's what you have then that's what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.whatever
(
  d date, 
  fruits varchar(255), 
  status varchar(12), 
  name   varchar(32)
 );

INSERT dbo.whatever VALUES
('20220102', 'bananas, apples and oranges', 'accepted', 'John'),   
('20220105', 'bananas and grapes', 'accepted', 'Mary'),
('20220108', 'kale and bananas', 'rejected', 'John');
```

You want to split strings but based on two delimiters. So before you split them, you can just replace one with the other:

```
SELECT w.d, fruit = LTRIM(f.value), w.status, w.name
FROM dbo.whatever AS w 
CROSS APPLY 
STRING_SPLIT(REPLACE(w.fruits, ' and ', ', '), ',') AS f;
```

Results:

| d | fruit | status | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-02 | bananas | accepted | John |
| 2022-01-02 | apples | accepted | John |
| 2022-01-02 | oranges | accepted | John |
| 2022-01-05 | bananas | accepted | Mary |
| 2022-01-05 | grapes | accepted | Mary |
| 2022-01-08 | kale | rejected | John |
| 2022-01-08 | bananas | rejected | John |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e7ba625706a26dc5edefebc6c51238d0)

Comment: Oh. That actually looks like a great idea. Thank you!